How does NDSolve deal with a delay variable
For a project I'm using an SIR model to simulate a Zika virus outbreak. And I solve a set of differential equations using NDSolve with specific initial conditions. However, a parameter I can vary is the Zika extrinsic incubation period, a delay, $\tau$.

S, I, R, L mean Susceptible, Infected, Recovered or Latent. And the subscript H indicates a human, while v indicates a vector.
Here are my differential equations:

And you notice in the last few equations we have a $S_{v}(t-\tau)$. My main question is how does Mathematica deal with this delay? As I only give it initial conditions for $t=0$. How does it know where to start a $S_{v}(-\tau)$. My lecturer hypothesized that Mathematica looks at what the function is doing at $S_{v}(\tau)$. And then reflecting that backwards to the other side of the y-axis. I hadn't originally thought this would be a problem until they had mentioned it so forgive me for poor explanations.
My Mathematica code:

a = 0.5*7;
b = (0.1 + 0.75 )/2;
c = (0.3 + 0.75)/2;
Subscript[N, h] = 207848000;
Subscript[μ, h] = 1/(75*52);
γ = 7/6;
Subscript[μ, v] = 0.025*7;
Subscript[N, v] = 1.5*Subscript[N, h];
τ = 8.2/7; 

T = 35;
(* Colours = Subscript[S, H]  Subscript[I, H]     Subscript[R, \
H]    Subscript[S, v]      Subscript[L, v]      Subscript[I, v]*)
Colours = {Orange, Red, Green, Purple, Black, Gray};

(*Equations*)

eqn1 = Subscript[S, h]'[
    t] == -a*b*
     Subscript[i, v][t]* (Subscript[S, h][t]/Subscript[N, h]) - 
    Subscript[μ, h]*Subscript[S, h][t] - + Subscript[μ, h]*
     Subscript[N, h];
eqn2 = Subscript[i, h]'[t] == 
   a*b*Subscript[i, v][
      t]*(Subscript[S, h][t]/Subscript[N, h] ) - (Subscript[μ, 
       h] + γ)*Subscript[i, h][t] ;
eqn3 = Subscript[R, h]'[t] == γ*Subscript[i, h][t] - 
    Subscript[μ, h]*Subscript[R, h][t];
eqn4 = Subscript[S, v]'[
    t] == -a*c*
     Subscript[S, v][t]*(Subscript[i, h][t]/Subscript[N, h] ) - 
    Subscript[μ, v]*Subscript[S, v][t] + 
    Subscript[μ, v]*Subscript[N, v];
eqn5 = Subscript[L, v]'[t] == 
   a*c*Subscript[S, v][t]*(Subscript[i, h][t]/Subscript[N, h] ) - 
    Subscript[μ, v]*Subscript[L, v][t] - 
    a*c*Subscript[S, v][
      t - τ]*(Subscript[i, h][t - τ]/Subscript[N, h] )* 
     Exp[-Subscript[μ, v]*τ];
eqn6 = Subscript[i, v]'[t] == 
   a*c*Subscript[S, v][t - τ]*
     Subscript[i, h][t - τ]/Subscript[N, h] * 
     Exp[-Subscript[μ, v]*τ] - 
    Subscript[μ, v]*Subscript[i, v][t];

initialConditions = {Subscript[S, h][0] == 207651021, 
   Subscript[i, h][0] == 196979, Subscript[R, h][0] == 0, 
   Subscript[S, v][0] == 311148456, Subscript[L, v][0] == 311772, 
   Subscript[i, v][0] == 311772};

sol = NDSolve[{eqn1, eqn2, eqn3, eqn4, eqn5, eqn6, 
    initialConditions}, {Subscript[S, h], Subscript[i, h], Subscript[
    R, h], Subscript[S, v], Subscript[L, v], Subscript[i, v]}, {t, 0, 
    T}];

(*All*)

Plot[
 Evaluate[{
    Subscript[S, h][t],
    Subscript[i, h][t],
    Subscript[R, h][t],
    Subscript[S, v][t],
    Subscript[L, v][t],
    Subscript[i, v][t]
    } /. sol],
 {t, 0, T},
 PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Colours ,
 PlotLegends -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(S\), \(H\)]\)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(H\)]\)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(R\), \(H\)]\)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(S\), \(v\)]\)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(L\), \(v\)]\)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(v\)]\)"},
 AxesLabel -> {"time (weeks)", "Population"},
 Epilog -> {{Dashed, Black, 
    Line[{{0, Subscript[N, h]}, {T, Subscript[N, h]}}], 
    Text["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(N\), \(H\)]\)", {T, Subscript[N, 
      h]}, {1, -1}]},
   {Dashed, Black, Line[{{0, Subscript[N, v]}, {T, Subscript[N, v]}}],
     Text["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(N\), \(v\)]\)", {T, Subscript[N, 
      v]}, {1, -1}]}
   }
 ]

And the graphical output:


Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please include Mathematica code (not images) that can be copied, pasted and executed. Thanks.

If I run your code, a message appears which says: NDSolve::ihist Conditions given at t = 0.` will be interpreted as initial history functions for t/;t<=0. Does this answer your question? :)

Ah yes I believe it does. So Mathematica defines t<0 to be the initial conditions, just starting off "flat". Much appreciated and quite easily found :D
